# no matter what I do I can't add realm to my project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, realm

this is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nuku.mc.populate_recyclerview"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {

            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
            classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.88.3"
        }
    }


    dependencies {

        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'


        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0'


        compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'

        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
                }
}
```

1)I tried to compile

2) I tried removing this line -> 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'

3) I tried without the build script{...} and added classpath with my other dependencies but it's still saying:

and my gradle is saying:
 Error(2,0) plugin with id 'realm-andoid' not found

Comment: First, check what @hi-im-frogatto said below. Second, both of your android gradle plugin and Realm are very old version, please try with new versions (there was a problem with android gradle plugin and old version Realm, see https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2348#issuecomment-189361216)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line to your *app module* `build.gradle` file.

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

And and these lines to the *project level* `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.1.0"
}
```

But it seems you add all of them in your *app module* `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I did I actually did all these things but still the same error :(

Comment: Thanks my problem is solved.Read the docs again and I was adding all these into my app module file.